# IE fails to display part of Wordpress website

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The website at http://belbelila.com is a simple wordpress blog. The website displays fine on FireFox but in IE 8 or 9 it is cut after the first post and I have no idea why. Here are screenshots of the difference:

Firefox:
[image]

IE8:
[image]
Can anyone give me a hint - what is causing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about this part, which is the result of copying and pasting from an Office product.

The usual culprit is Microsoft Word:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <w:WordDocument> <w:View>Normal</w:View>
<w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom> <w:HyphenationZone>21</w:HyphenationZone> 
<w:Compatibility> <w:BreakWrappedTables /> <w:SnapToGridInCell />
<w:WrapTextWithPunct /> <w:UseAsianBreakRules /> </w:Compatibility> 
<w:BrowserLevel>MicrosoftInternetExplorer4</w:BrowserLevel> </w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 10]> <mce:style><!   /* Style Definitions */
table.MsoNormalTable    {mso-style-name:"Нормална таблица";     
mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;  mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;  mso-style-noshow:yes; 
mso-style-parent:"";    mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;    
mso-para-margin:0cm;    mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;     
mso-pagination:widow-orphan;    font-size:10.0pt;   
font-family:"Times New Roman";} --> <!--[endif]-->
```

(*I added line breaks*)

Remove that, and I'm 99% sure it will be fixed (I didn't test it).

The IE comments inside that block are somehow malformed/mismatched, so IE thinks that most of the HTML is a comment.

Comment: thank you, I made this website for a friend of mine and he is the one posting.. I'm sure this is the problem

Comment: No problem! I'm not sure how to fix Wordpress to "properly accept" content pasted from Microsoft Word, but there will be a way.

Comment: See this answer on wordpress.stackexchange on [how to paste content from Microsoft Word.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/819/how-can-i-filter-microsoft-word-gunk-from-pasted-content/827#827)